# Enter data into JSON variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, database

I tried a lot for it but I cannot find solution.

I had this following JSON variable, it consists of two names rocky and jhon.

```
 var names = [
          "rocky",
           "jhon"
           ];
```

Now I want to enter a new value into this var names as sham such that it should show in the text file also.

I mean after doing operation the var  should look like :

```
 var names = [
          "rocky",
          "jhon",
           "sham"
           ];
```

That means on seeing .html code file I have to view this updated value
in clear it should work like insert command in sql. 
I tried using push command but it doesn't work.

Comment: Firstly, that's an array, not JSON. Secondly, I can't understand what your goal is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  [.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```
names.push('sham');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/tQqYD/)

**code**

```
var names = [
    "rocky",
    "jhon"];
names.push('sham');
console.log(names); //output ["rocky", "jhon", "sham"]
```

Read more about [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 3):

**before**

```
 var names = [
          "rocky",
           "jhon"
           ];
```

**apply**

```
names .push("sham");
```

**after**

```
var names = [
          "rocky",
          "jhon",
           "sham"
           ];
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/tQqYD/3/)**

reference **[array](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/arrays/)**  & **[push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)**

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
var names = [
          "rocky",
           "jhon"
           ];
names.push('shyam');
alert(names); //For Test
```

working demo : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shree/fZZaa/)

Comment: Thanks for help MR.Shree but i when i close the file and reopen it it doesn't showing 'shyam' it only showing 'rocky' and 'jhon'. How can make new value as permanent like previous values.

Comment: You must store a value in session or in database or in cookies to retrieve again that value.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
var names = [ "rocky","john"];    
  //Or You can use splice to insert in middle  like  
       names.splice(1,0,"Sham")     // Out Put [ "rocky","Sham","john"  ]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fZZaa/1/)

Hope this Helps You .